# How can I convert a double value to time?

Tags: php, time

How can I convert a double value to time? For example, if the input is `7.50` then the output would be `7.30`.

Comment: ie how i get the enterd time 7.50 as 7.30  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$input = "7.5";
list($hours, $wrongMinutes) = explode('.', $input);
$minutes = ($wrongMinutes < 10 ? $wrongMinutes * 10 : $wrongMinutes) * 0.6;
echo $hours . ':' . $minutes;
```

Answer (score 3):

Get only a nondecimal rest by

```
$val = $input - floor( $input );
```

Then convert values from 0-99 to 0-60 by (exactly it is 0.99... to 0.60):

```
$val = $val*0.6;
```

At the end add the computed precision value to the decimal part of the input:

```
$output = floor( $input ) + $val
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
<?php
$input = 7.50;
$hours = intval($input);
$realPart = $input - $hours;
$minutes = intval( $realPart * 60);
echo $hours.":".$minutes;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the integral part of the number: These are your hours
2. Find the fractional part of the number; multiply it by 60 and round down (floor()). These are your seconds.
   That's all there is to it.